# Проблема с версткой. Сдвиг всей страница вниз.

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, flexbox

Не могу понять причину проблемы. Вся страница отображается со сдвигом. 
При чем в браузере Firefox все ок. Chrome же отображает криво. 
Использовал flexbox и bootstrap.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. 
https://energy-shop.com.ua/

[image: скрин сайта]

Comment: Ибо у Вас там текст выводиться после тега body `&#65279`, так что это проблема не верстки, а `php` скорее всего.

Comment: https://simplamarket.com/blog/bom-ili-tainstvennyj-simvol-65279 - возможно поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью скрипта нашел какие файлы с кодировкой UTF-8 with BOM и сохранил их уже с UTF-8